# Call to AsyncTask error: LoadBookBuyInfo cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, callback, android-asynctask, fragment

In my call to my AsyncTask, new LoadBookBuyInfo().execute();, I receive the error: "LoadBookBuyInfo cannot be resolved to a type".  I'm using fragments and I've scoured the internet for an answer but to no avail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Here's my code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buy_tbfrag, container, false);

    //bookLV = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    //bookLV = getListView();
    bookLV = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    //enables filtering for the contents of the given ListView bookLV
    bookLV.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    //Search inputed book title
    titleSearch = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.titleSearch);


    return view;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    System.out.println("onActivityCreated executed");

    bookArray = new ArrayList<Bookinfo>();

    //**************************************************************************************//
    //*******************New Async Task & JSON Parser code starts here**********************//
    //**************************************************************************************//

    //Load bookArray in Background Thread
    new LoadBookBuyInfo().execute();


    //Background AsyncTask to load all BookBuyInfo by making Http Request
    class LoadBookBuyInfo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        //Show Progress Dialog before starting background thread
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //pDialog = new ProgressDialog(BuyFragTab); //might can only be activity
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());//might can only be activity
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Books...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        //Get BookBuyInfo Data
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            //Building parameters
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> bookValues = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            //getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(BOOKBUY_URL, "GET", bookValues);

            //Check logcat for JSON response
            Log.d("Book Buy JSON: ", json.toString());

            //Get JSON Data
            try {
                bookBuyInfo = json.getJSONArray("books");

                //bookArray = new ArrayList<Bookinfo>();
                //loop through all books and load data
                for (int i = 0; i < bookBuyInfo.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject b = bookBuyInfo.getJSONObject(i);
                    ...
                    (book code setup)}
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

    //}

        //After completing background task, dismiss the progress dialog
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) { // might need to be (String result) here
            //dismiss the dialog after getting all the records
            pDialog.dismiss();
            //update UI from background thread
            //runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                    adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.buy_tbfrag, bookArray);
                    bookLV.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you placed your AsyncTask class inside onActivityCreated method. Move the whole AsyncTask class outside of this method and then call it from there.

Comment: Can it be placed in the onCreateView method or entirely somewhere else?

Comment: AsyncTask is a class. You can place an inner class inside your activity but it must be outside any other methods. You call it properly just move it outside of the method to the main class (your activity)